# How to Insert Multiple Rows in One Table? (MVC 5 ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would want to insert multiple entries in my table called 'sibling' using it's Create Method (which I generated automatically using Scaffolding methods). I already made the form dynamic in adding the fields. However, when I click on the Submit button it only gets the first entry.

I sort of have an idea by implementing 'foreach' in the said method but I can't seem to find an answer that is spot on. Especially for my case I just want to modify the Create Method for 'sibling' which was generated automatically (if there is such a way without having to create a new method - but if not I am fine with a different approach as well).

This is my SiblingController:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var sib = new sibling();
        sib.child_id = id;
        return View(sib);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "sibling_id,child_id,age,gender")] sibling sibling)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.siblings.Add(sibling);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.child_id = new SelectList(db.children, "child_id", "last_name", sibling.child_id);
        return View(sibling);
    }
```

This is my Create.cshtml for Sibling:

```
@model dummyApp.Schema.TestModels.sibling

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Coding

    $("#numBox").change(function () {
        var htmlString = "";
        var len = $(this).val();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            htmlString += ' <div class="form-group">\
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.child_id, "child_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })\
                                <div class="col-md-10">\
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.child_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})\
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.child_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="form-group">\
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })\
                                <div class="col-md-10">\
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })\
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="form-group">\
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })\
                                <div class="col-md-10">\
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })\
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        ';
        }
        $("#adtnl_fields").html(htmlString);
    })
</script>
}
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>sibling</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <!--
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sibling_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sibling_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sibling_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    -->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Number of Siblings:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="number" id="numBox" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.child_id, "child_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*Html.DropDownList("child_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.child_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.child_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    -->

    <!-- Div for additional fields -->
    <div id="adtnl_fields">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

This is my 'sibling.cs':

```
public partial class sibling
{
    public int sibling_id { get; set; }
    public int child_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> age { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }

    public virtual child child { get; set; }
}
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You need to post a list of Siblings to your action method and your action method should also accept a collection of Siblings object. Also you cannot use an HtmlHelper method call (Which is a server method) inside your javascript method which executes on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method in EF-6

```
IList<Student> newStudents = new List<Student>();
newStudents.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Student1 by addrange" });
newStudents.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Student2 by addrange" });
newStudents.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Student3 by addrange" });

using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    context.Students.AddRange(newStudents);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: May you please expound more on this? My case has dynamic fields in the 'sibling' Create Form. I need to get all 'sibling' entries which can [x] in number and not just 3 entries. Thank you!